# How to improve my question? I'm looking for photo taking app

Tags: support, questions, specific-question

This question: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/36218/can-anyone-recommend-an-android-photo-taking-app

I read the blog post about so called "[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)." But I guess my question is, or can be improved to be rather on the good side of the question.

- I was rather specific
- I don't plan to spend money
- I'm looking for a solution to a problem

Answer (score 1):

Being specific and/or spending money isn't the problem.  The problem is that product recommendations don't age well (there may and likely will be better options later).  They can be very narrow in scope (not all photo apps work on all phones).  Simply put, they don't really fit well as a Q/A format because either the question won't help a broad audience or the answer won't remain valid beyond a short window of time.

The closest thing I can think of that would be an on-topic question would be something like "What features are helpful for a camera app?"  which may end up including some examples of software that has the features and may end up mentioning features that you hadn't even thought about.

Another question that might work would be "Have Smartphone Cameras caught up with Point and Shoots?"  This is also a broadly useful question that extends a little beyond particular apps, but would likely end up having some mentioned as examples.  That question might not be ideal either though since it is rather broad and potentially subjective.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really even so much that it's a shopping question.  It's not whether the f/2.8 lens is worth the extra $$ over the f/4 version, where people might have experience with those lenses and could comment (although subjectively).  But it's more the kind of question that all we can really do is Google for you.  There exists an app, or there doesn't.

And this might just be me, but you've listed requirements, but what specifically is that problem you're trying to solve? I don't actually understand what you're after.  You want to press a physical button rather than the touchscreen virtual one?